# Move along track in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

I have a problem with making a game like Sonic Rivals. As you see in the game Sonic tracking his way from down to up and from right to left. In the game, I'm just pressing right and left and Sonic chooses his way but in the blender game engine nothing helps me. I tried track to prop and constraint, can you help me please [image] [image]